# Bluetooth headset no sound (but looks correct)

Tags: 21.10

I have a bluetooth headset which is connected correctly using HSP/HFP. I see the output and input volume sliders (speaker and mic) for the device, but no sound comes out of the headset (and the microphone input doesn't work).

Details:

- I am running Ubuntu 21.10 (I have tried Ubuntu 18 LTS as well)
- I have tried both Pulseaudio as well as Pipewire (as per advice)
- Tried both CSVD & mSBC (for HSP/HFP)
- When an app plays a sound I see the volume control thinks sound is playing, but I hear nothing
- Weirdly, when I drag the volume control the max I hear a bluetooth chime in my headset, so it's doing something at least (not that this is not the normal Ubuntu volume test blip, it is something internal to the headset)
- If I use the A2DP Sink, audio works correctly!

(FWIW, headset is the Shure Aonic 215 TW2)

Any suggestions?

Thank you!